# BCD format in 9bit serial protocol

Tags: python-2.7

I have 9 bit serial protocol.
Documentation says this:
For UARTs/DUARTs that do not directly support wakeup mode, the parity bit
can be used in place of the wakeup bit.

And i use that with USB to Serial pl2303:

```
import time, serial

if ser.is_open == False:
try:
    ser.port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
    ser.open()
except SerialException:
    ser.port = '/dev/ttyUSB1'
    ser.open()

def get_curent_credit():
    ser.parity = serial.PARITY_MARK
    ser._stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
    cmd = '1A'
    cmd = mashin_n + cmd
    cmd = cmd + crc_sas(cmd)
    ser.flushInput()

    # Not needed, but without this command not work
    ser.write('80'.decode('hex')) 
    time.sleep(1)

    # cmd = 011Aa603
    ser.write(cmd.decode('hex'))
    response =  ser.read(8).encode('hex')
    crc_sas(response, chk=True)
    return int(response[4:-4])*0.01
```

This code works.
But if i try different command like.
018A001000000253ca
where:
01 = adress 1b

8A = command 1b

00100000 = 4 BCD

02 = tax 1b

53ca = CRC

This not work

i think the problem is in BCD
but no have idea how to fix it

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let alone give answer.
The problem is bit 9.

If we send in byte format bit 9 is 01 or parity mark

else bit 9 is 00 or parity space